# Use Stimulus to update selects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs

I am deriving from [this tutorial](https://onrails.blog/2018/10/04/stimulus-js-tutorial-using-multi-select-to-pare-down-a-large-set-of-data/), and I've gotten the Stimulus controller to work; however, the result is not rendering as expected.

I am using this to update several select boxes, starting with country to filter the data in state_province one.

in my _address.html.haml I have:

```
.fieldset.border.border-dark.ps-4.pe-4.pt-4.mb-4
    = f.fields_for :address, Address.new do |a| 
        %div{data:{controller: "select-filter", select:{filter:{url: "#{filter_states_path}", form: a}} }}
            %legend Primary Address
...

            .form-floating.mb-4
                = a.select :country_id, options_for_select(Country.all.collect { |c| [ "#{sanitize(c.unicode_flag)} #{c.name} (#{c.country_code})" , c.id] }), {prompt: "Choose One. . . "}, {class: "form-select form-select-lg border border-dark", required: true, data:{action: "select-filter#change"}}
                = a.label :country_id, "Country"

...

                .col-md-4.mb-4
                    = render "admin/addresses/state_province", a: a, states: states

...
```

in my _state_province.html.haml, I am currently checking if states is NOT nil and if so, put a paragraph in there with "Hi you" as the text.  Right now, Right now, states is NOT nil, and I've confirmed this with rails console by running the same query in there.  Count returns 56 whi is the actual number of records.

```
.form-floating{ data:{select:{filter:{target: "states"}}} }
    - if states.nil?
        %p Hi you

    -#= a.select :state_province_id, options_for_select(states.collect { |c| [ "#{c.code} #{c.name}", c.id] }), {prompt: "Choose one. . . "}, {class: "form-select form-select-lg border border-dark", required: true }
    -#= a.label :state_province_id, "State / Province"
```

in my filter_states.html.haml, I have the following:

```
= render "admin/addresses/state_province", a: @a, states: @states
```

in my AddressesController I have the following:

```
class Admin::AddressesController < ApplicationController
    def filter_states
        @states = StateProvince.where(country_id: params[:country]).all
        @a = params[:form]
    end
end
```

in my routes, I have:

```
post 'filter_states', to: 'admin/addresses#filter_states'
```

and in my select_filter_controller.js, I have:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "states" ]

  change(event) {
    var form_var = this.data.get("form")
    fetch(this.data.get("url"), { 
      method: 'POST', 
      body: JSON.stringify( { country: [...event.target.selectedOptions].map(option => option.value), form: form_var }),
      credentials: "include",
      dataType: 'script',
      headers: {
        "X-CSRF-Token": getMetaValue("csrf-token"),
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(html => {
        this.statesTarget.innerHTML = html
      })
  }
}

function getMetaValue(name) {
  const element = document.head.querySelector(`meta[name="${name}"]`)
  return element.getAttribute("content")
}
```

so a few things:

1. When the Stimulus replaces _state_province.html.haml through the filter_states.html.haml, it renders the entire application.html.haml inside that small part of the window, instead of JUST the partial.  Almost like an iframe for the whole application.
2. It appears that I'm not passing the form's a variable into Stimulus and then to the controller and then back into the new partial (it works fine directly from _address, but when the content is replaced by filter_states, the "a" variable doesn't work).  So I think that's where the private method error is coming from.

Did I miss something here?

Below is a screenshot of what the returned partial looks like
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `a` variable is a form builder object, a ruby object. you can't pass it as a `param`, all you get is a string in `data-select-filter-form`.  in your controller `filter_states` has to render inputs without the use of a form builder.

Comment: Thanks!  Building the select and label manually worked.  there's still the minor issue of it rendering the entire application.html.haml inside that partial though, instead of JUST the partial itself.

Comment: Well, apparently I don't need a full filter_states.html.haml file, instead I added the line in the controller action itself: render partial: "admin/addresses/state_province" and in the partial I added "- states = @states" to the top so that the variables work across different parts of the app.